# Best device for SVG graphics in R?

Tags: r, svg

I'd like to export SVG graphics from R. There appear to be two alternatives: RSvgDevice and Cairo. Can anyone comment on these packages? Is either the default, or clearly better than the other?

Many thanks,

Comment: I highly recommend `svglite` is you're still interested in generating SVG files from R: https://github.com/hadley/svglite

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't comment definitively other than to say that I use Cairo all the time to create high-quality images, and have had great experience with it.  It can target many different output formats beyond SVG.

Comment: The drawback of Cairo is that it does not support text elements in SVG. Each character is placed individually, so in when you open the generated file in Inkscape you will find that each character is a separate object. That makes touching up the output pretty cumbersome...

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know,  there are other packages you could try: gridSVG, SVGAnnotation and RSVGTipsDevice. You will find lots of examples and different discussions of these approaches in some [slides by Paul Murrel](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/Talks/Genentech2011/gridsvg.pdf) (author of gridSVG) and in a [paper by the authors of SVGAnnotation](http://www.omegahat.org/SVGAnnotation/JSSPaper.html).